# Are there any known collisions of a "long" (64 bit) OpenPGP key ID?

Tags: key-management, brute-force, pgp, gnupg, openpgp

We know that the "short" 32 bit OpenPGP key IDs can be easily brute-forced and the recommendation is to use the "long" 64 bit IDs or full 160 bit SHA1 fingerprint.  However I am concerned that the "long" key IDs may also be brute-forceable in the not-so-distant future.

Given that a collision would generally be a precursor to a successful preimage attack, are there any known examples of a collision being found for a long key ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenPGP IDs are portions of the SHA-1 fingerprint, as [defined in the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-12.2). A short key ID is the last 32 bits, and the long key ID is the last 64 bits. A collision typically takes an average of 2<sup>n/2</sup> operations, where *n* is the size of the hash in bits. Generating collisions for short IDs and long IDs is trivial, requiring an average of 2<sup>16</sup> and 2<sup>32</sup> operations, respectively. A collision in this case is defined as creating two differing hash inputs which have identical digests. It is actually even possible to collide the full SHA-1 fingerprint, as [Google has shown](https://shattered.io/). Colliding a full OpenPGP fingerprint requires nothing more than colliding a single SHA-1 hash. This is difficult, but possible with sufficient computing power.

Creating a preimage is different. Unlike a collision, a preimage attack requires creating an input that matches a specific hash digest. The attacker does not get to provide both inputs, only one, making it a much more difficult attack. Unlike a collision attack, a preimage attack requires a full 2<sup>n</sup> operations for a hash of size *n*. Because of this, creating a preimage for a short ID requires only 2<sup>32</sup> operations, which is downright trivial. Doing the same for a long ID requires 2<sup>64</sup> operations, which is not easy, but far from impossible. Doing the same with the full 160-bit fingerprint is simply impossible with current technology.

In summary:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+
|             | Collision |  Preimage  |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| Short ID    |  Trivial  |    Easy    |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| Long ID     |   Easy    |    Hard    |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| Fingerprint |   Hard    | Impossible |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: Generic collision of 160-bit SHA-1 is 2^80, but the Google+Stevens et al break is 2^63.1. However it requires substantial freedom in fairly large inputs (they use PDF files), and I'm not sure if that can be obtained for (otherwise valid) PGP keys.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Specifically, IIRC, they had the freedom to manipulate the data in a non-displayed JPG image within the PDF.

Comment: @TripeHound Remember that the OpenPGP standard can hold a lot of non-displayed data that is free to be modified.